# Custom AbstractEndpoint listening to "/" (root)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-starter

I've implemented a starter that configures Swagger the way I like. In addition, I'd like to redirect every call to the app's root URL (e.g. `localhost:8080`) to `/swagger-ui.html`.
Therefore, I added an own `AbstractEndpoint` which is instantiated in the `@Configuration` class as follows:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("swagger")
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    ...

    @Bean
    public RootEndpoint rootEndpoint() {
        return new RootEndpoint();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnBean(RootEndpoint.class)
    @ConditionalOnEnabledEndpoint("root")
    public RootMvcEndpoint rootMvcEndpoint(RootEndpoint rootEndpoint) {
        return new RootMvcEndpoint(rootEndpoint);
    }
}
```

The respective classes look like this:

```
public class RootEndpoint extends AbstractEndpoint<String> {

    public RootEndpoint() {
        super("root");
    }

    @Override
    public String invoke() {
        return ""; // real calls shall be handled by RootMvcEndpoint
    }
}
```

and

```
public class RootMvcEndpoint extends EndpointMvcAdapter {

    public RootMvcEndpoint(RootEndpoint delegate) {
        super(delegate);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.GET}, produces = { "*/*" })
    public void redirect(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws IOException {
        httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/swagger-ui.html");
    }
}
```

As stated in `public RootEndpoint()`, the custom Endpoint is bound to `/root`. Unfortunately, I can't specify `super("");` or `super("/");` as those values throw an exception (`Id must only contains letters, numbers and '_'`).

How can I achieve having a custom Endpoint listening to the root URL in a starter using `@Configuration` files to instantiate beans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with an easier approach by adding a `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` bean in the `@Configuration`:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurerAdapter redirectToSwagger() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addViewController("").setViewName("redirect:/swagger-ui.html");
        }
    };
}
```